# python 2d array indexing: setting a value changing whole column?

Tags: python

It might be a very stupid question but I just don't understand this code:

```
>>> a=[[0]*3]*3
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> a[0][1]=3
>>> a
[[0, 3, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 3, 0]]
```

Why a call a[0][1] will initialize the whole second column to be 3?

Comment: python 2.7.5 on mac 10.10.3

Answer (score 0):

This is because `a[0][1]` actually is the reference to the same lists. When you use * operator to duplicate elements into a list, these duplicate elements are not individually stored in the memory. They point to the same list, so if you modify one list, all the lists would be modified.

Comment: I see. I got misled by some answers on stack overflow saying this would initialize a 2-D array. which doesn't.